# Process Explorer won't launch "Find Handle or DLL..." window

Tags: windows, windows-11, user-accounts, process-explorer

There's some really strange behavior going on where when I launch Process Explorer (`procexp.exe`) on one account, it won't launch the `Find Handle or DLL...` window. All that happens is the Process Explorer window loses focus.

However, it works perfectly if I use Process Explorer from a different user account (both accounts are Administrators and can run the program in elevated mode).

- I checked that it isn't hiding the window somewhere off-screen by using <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to view all the current windows.
- I wiped all the settings in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sysinternals` via regedit which didn't seem to help.

Comment: Something works in one User Account and not another, is normally a sign of a damaged User Profile where the App does not work.

Comment: Is the dialog window perhaps hiding behind the main Process Explorer window? Try moving the window aside.

Comment: @Destroy666 ProcExp is a standalone executable and is not installed.